# Where do i implement the JS part from codepen.io when I want to add this to my rails app

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Sorry for my newbe question I am very new to this and I couldn't find any similar questions on stackoverflow.

I found this very cool pen on codepen.io. 
http://codepen.io/yilgul/pen/qmXQOV

I want to implement this on my rails-app as I try to learn. 
Without any prior knowledge of JS.

The HTML part is just a div with a ID.

```
    <div id="box"></div>
```

As I look at the css i see that the body has a background color, but i would like this feature as a section on the page and not the whole page.

```
body { 
font-family: sans-serif;
background: #ccc; 
padding: 100px;
```

So I also gave it a class "box" as following

```
<div class="box1">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

and adressed this class in the custom.scss file.

For the JS part, I put this part in the application.js just after the require_* statements. Is this the right way?

A long story short, I can't get it to display. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Much appriciated

Comment: Can you share some relevant code ?

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: @AgamBanga No erros, All is rendered well. But all I see is a static section with a background color.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ozan What would u like to see? Excuse me for incompleteness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this:

Add your js code directly to application.js

Add a new js file and write `//= require your-file-name` in your application.js

I will prefer the second one

Comment: And make sure you you include application.js in your layouts